# Why we are not using Lagrangian instead of Hamiltonian in non-relativistic quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

Why we are not using Lagrangian instead of Hamiltonian in non-relativistic quantum mechanics?

Comment: When do you mean? Both are used in qm

Comment: @user47014 will you please elaborate with example

Comment: The linked question goes onto it